# gridview inside gridview calculation in asp.net c# using javaScript/jquery Client side

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

i have two gridviews inside gridview having footer that total price and tax show in footer and all inside gridviews Gross total show in gridview1 footer

```
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Category">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblcategoryname" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ItemName")%>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    Gross Total
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select Products">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <table width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowFooter="true">
                                    <Columns>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ItemName">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblItemName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ItemName")%>'></asp:Label>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblprice" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Price")%>' />
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="tax">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lbltax" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("tax")%>' />
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtCalcQuantity" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Quantity")%>' />
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                            <FooterTemplate>
                                                Total
                                            </FooterTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblTotal" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                            <FooterTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblGrossTotal" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label>
                                            </FooterTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total tax">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblTotaltax" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                            <FooterTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblGrossTotaltax" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label>
                                            </FooterTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                    </Columns>
                                </asp:GridView>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblGrossTotal" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblGrossTotaltax" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

but my problem is getting footer values are same, but we need individual totals and tax for each and every inside grid (GridView2) and Gross total in Main Grid (GridView1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my Requirement
//JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function funcsum() {
        var table = document.getElementById("GridView1");
        var Taxsum = 0, pricesum = 0;
        for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) //setting the incrementor=0, but if you have a header set it to 1 
        {
            if (i != (table.rows.length - 1)) {
                var gvname = 'GridView1_GridView2_' + (i - 1);
                var subtable = document.getElementById(gvname);
                var totTax = 0, totamount = 0;
                for (var j = 1; j < subtable.rows.length; j++) {
                    if (j != (subtable.rows.length - 1)) {
                        var Tax = 'GridView1_GridView2_' + (i - 1) + '_lbltax_' + (j - 1);
                        var lbltax = document.getElementById(Tax).innerHTML;
                        var dpprice = 'GridView1_GridView2_' + (i - 1) + '_lblprice_' + (j - 1);
                        var lblprice = document.getElementById(dpprice).innerHTML;
                        var Quantity = 'GridView1_GridView2_' + (i - 1) + '_txtQuantity_' + (j - 1);
                        var txtQuantity = document.getElementById(Quantity).value;
                        var totalTax = 'GridView1_GridView2_' + (i - 1) + '_lblTotaltax_' + (j - 1);
                        var lbltotalTax = document.getElementById(totalTax).innerHTML;
                        var totamt = 'GridView1_GridView2_' + (i - 1) + '_lblTotal_' + (j - 1);
                        var lblTotal = document.getElementById(totamt).innerHTML;
                        if (isNaN(txtQuantity) || txtQuantity == '') {
                            txtQuantity = 0;
                            document.getElementById(Quantity).value = txtQuantity;
                        }
                        lbltotalTax = (parseFloat(lbltax) * parseFloat(txtQuantity)).toString();
                        lblTotal = (parseFloat(lblprice) * parseFloat(txtQuantity)).toString();
                        document.getElementById(totalTax).innerHTML = lbltotalTax;
                        document.getElementById(totamt).innerHTML = lblTotal;
                        totTax = totTax + parseFloat(lbltotalTax);
                        totamount = totamount + parseFloat(lblTotal);
                    }
                    else {
                        var lbl_totalTax = document.getElementById('GridView1_GridView2_' + (i - 1) + '_lblGrossTotaltax').innerHTML;
                        var lblGrossTotal = document.getElementById('GridView1_GridView2_' + (i - 1) + '_lblGrossTotal').innerHTML;
                        lbl_totalTax = totTax;
                        lblGrossTotal = totamount;
                        document.getElementById('GridView1_GridView2_' + (i - 1) + '_lblGrossTotaltax').innerHTML = totTax;
                        document.getElementById('GridView1_GridView2_' + (i - 1) + '_lblGrossTotal').innerHTML = totamount;
                    }
                }
                Taxsum = Taxsum + parseFloat(totTax);
                pricesum = pricesum + parseFloat(totamount);
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById('GridView1_lblGrossTotaltax').innerHTML = Taxsum;
                document.getElementById('GridView1_lblGrossTotal').innerHTML = pricesum;
            }
        }
    } 
</script>










            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Category">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblcategoryname" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ItemName")%>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    Gross Total
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select Products">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <table width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowFooter="true">
                                    <Columns>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ItemName">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblItemName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ItemName")%>'></asp:Label>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblprice" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Price")%>' />
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="tax">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lbltax" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("tax")%>' />
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Quantity")%>' onchange="funcsum()" />
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                            <FooterTemplate>
                                                Total
                                            </FooterTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblTotal" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                            <FooterTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblGrossTotal" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label>
                                            </FooterTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total tax">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblTotaltax" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                            <FooterTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblGrossTotaltax" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label>
                                            </FooterTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                    </Columns>
                                </asp:GridView>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblGrossTotal" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblGrossTotaltax" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

i Have done for CheckBox inside 2 Gridview's You Can Edit this with Textbox for Your Requirement
//JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">      
 function CheckAll(HeaderCheckBox,chkItem,gView)
 {

  var gv=document.getElementById(gView.id);
  //alert(gv.id.replace("_ctl01_HeaderCheckBox",""));
  var _hoursGrid=gv.id.replace("_ctl01_HeaderCheckBox","");
  //alert(document.getElementById(gv.id.replace("_ctl01_HeaderCheckBox","")).rows.length);
  //alert(gv.id.replace("HeaderCheckBox","SelectCheckBox"));
  var len=document.getElementById(_hoursGrid).rows.length;
  //alert(document.getElementById(gv.id));
  if(document.getElementById(gv.id).checked)
  {
 // alert("p");
       for(var i=2;i<=len;i++)
       {
         if(i<10)
         {
        // alert(_hoursGrid+'_ctl0'+i+'_'+chkItem);
          document.getElementById(_hoursGrid+'_ctl0'+i+'_'+chkItem).checked=true;
         }
         else
         {
          document.getElementById(_hoursGrid+'_ctl'+i+'_'+chkItem).checked=true;
         }
       }
  }
  else
  {
       for(var i=2;i<=len;i++)
       {
         if(i<10)
         {
          document.getElementById(_hoursGrid+'_ctl0'+i+'_'+chkItem).checked=false;
         }
         else
         {
          document.getElementById(_hoursGrid+'_ctl'+i+'_'+chkItem).checked=false;
         }
       }          
  }
 }
</script>
```

```
                                    <ItemTemplate>

                                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="border_bottom_none">
                                            <tr height="20px" class="baground_none">
                                                <td align="left" style="background-color: White; color: Black;">
                                                    &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="DateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# String.Format("{0:D}", Eval("Date")) %>'
                                                        Font-Size="11px"></asp:Label>
                                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="DateHiddenField" runat="server" Value='<%# String.Format("{0:d}", Eval("Date")) %>' />
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <asp:GridView ID="HoursGridView" Width="100%" PagerStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                                                        AllowPaging="false" EmptyDataText="No records found" EmptyDataRowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                                                        BorderWidth="0" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="grid_body floatingtalbe">
                                                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="grid" />
                                                        <RowStyle CssClass="grid_text" />
                                                        <PagerStyle CssClass="manag_user_num" />
                                                        <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="grid_box_colr" />
                                                        <Columns>
                                                            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="2%" ItemStyle-CssClass="text_box_req">
                                                                <HeaderTemplate>
                                                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="HeaderCheckBox" runat="server" onClick="CheckAll('HeaderCheckBox','SelectCheckBox',this);" />
                                                                </HeaderTemplate>
                                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="SelectCheckBox" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="SelectCheckBox_CheckedChanged"
                                                                        AutoPostBack="true" />
                                                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="JobIdHiddenField" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("Job_Id") %>' />
                                                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="EmployeeHiddenField" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("Employee_Id") %>' />
                                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Job #" DataField="Job_Number" ItemStyle-CssClass="color_black" />                                                                
                                                        </Columns>
                                                    </asp:GridView>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
```